# How to filter object list based on date property on kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin, date, filter

What I am trying to do is given a list of objects `responseList<Object>` in which the objects have a date field on string format "2015-01-16", filter the list to only get objects form last month or the current year and add the filtered objects to a new list.

The first thing that I have done is convert the string into date and the result is "Fri Jan 16 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2015".

using:

```
val dateformated = getFormatedDate(object.date)

    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.time = dateFormated; //date formatted is the string converted to date
    var responseMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    var responseYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
```

I am able to retrieve both month and year of the response and using this:

```
val now: LocalDate = LocalDate.now() 
val lastMonth = now.minusMonths(1).month
val thisYear = now.year
```

I get the current year and month

What I am failing to is filtering the object list based on the requirement to create another list.
Any help or suggestions would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Test
fun filterDateListByLastMonthOrThisYear() {
    val fakeDateOne = LocalDate.of(2023, 2, 1)
    val fakeDateTwo = LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 12)
    val fakeDateThree = LocalDate.of(1999, 12, 31)
    val fakeDateFour = LocalDate.of(2023, 2, 2)
    val fakeDateFive = LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 3)

    val datesList = listOf(
        fakeDateOne,
        fakeDateTwo,
        fakeDateThree,
        fakeDateFour,
        fakeDateFive
    )
    val today = LocalDate.now()
    val lastMonth = today.month.minus(1)
    val thisYear = today.year

    val expected = listOf(fakeDateOne, fakeDateFour, fakeDateFive)

    val actual = datesList.filter { it.year == thisYear || it.month == lastMonth }

    assertEquals(expected, actual)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will checkit out